# Create multiple columns from one based on different symbols

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a digital marketing manager and am trying to breakdown my campaigns for sliced analysis. My campaigns are listed in one column as follows.

```
  FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}
  FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}
  ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e}
```

I would like to separate each first based on - then | and then on {.

[image: Expected output]

Is it possible to do this via PostgreSQL based on different symbols?

Thank you

Comment: Would a single array or json column suffice or do you truly need multiple columns? If so, are you needing exactly 3 columns?

Comment: Hello Joe, I need 5 columns as stated in the picture.  They unfortunately have to be 5 as I need to use these for reporting via an excel pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at string functions, which are pretty common in any query language.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

`substring()` combined with `position()` will help you achieve what you need.
Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `string_to_array()`:

```
-- test data
with data (src) as (
 values 
  ('FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}'),
  ('FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}'),
  ('ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e}')
)
-- actual query
select (string_to_array(trim(split_part(src, '|', 1)), '-'))[1] as cola,
       (string_to_array(trim(split_part(src, '|', 1)), '-'))[2] as colb,
       (string_to_array(trim(split_part(src, '|', 1)), '-'))[3] as colc,
       (string_to_array(trim(split_part(src, '|', 2)), ' '))[1] as cold,
       (string_to_array(trim(split_part(src, '|', 2)), ' '))[2] as cole
from data
```

Returns:

```
cola | colb | colc     | cold         | cole
-----+------+----------+--------------+-----
FR   | SRC  | PLATFORM | MISC         | {bw}
FR   | SRC  | M2M sim  | Sim          | {bw}
ES   | SRC  | IOT      | Connectivity | {e}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much.  Would it be possible to provide further logic as I do not fully understand what was done.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following (there are many methods to split your string, but here's one)

```
 SELECT split_part(your_col,'-',1) cola,
 split_part(your_col,'-',2) colb,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,'-',2),' | ',1) colc,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,' | ',2),' {',1) cold,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,'{',2),'}',1) cole
/* or 
   split_part(your_col,'{',2) cole
*/
 FROM your_table
```

the split_part function is simply a function that divides a string into parts byt the 2nd parameter-- so in this case, it divides your_col into separate strings, dividing at the '{' (in one example above), and it returns one part (part number is the 3rd parameter).

So by using this multiple times, and using it to further divide the strings up, we should have the expected results.

Comment: Hello Joe,  Thank you for the response.  Would you mind providing a  little bit of an explanation as to how this query works? What functions do the numbers play?  What if I would want to have this formula populate also columns that perhaps could apply if the criteria was bigger. An example could be if the campaign was named as follows; FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC | SIM |USA {bw}.  I would basically be creating extra columns within the new table for the possibility for SIM and USA populate.  Many thanks in advanced.